# How POSTMAN sends XHR request wothout OPTION request

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

i want to know how POSTMAN send XHR request without OPTION request.

Comment: By Postman you mean the *extension*?  These run with privileges that exclude them from XHR/SOP restrictions.

Comment: here i have installed CORS extension and then i'm calling web service but my service call sends another OPTION request where POSTMAN's dosen't so whats the main difference